ARCore Geospatial on Android mobile without Depth API capabilities
I've been developing an AR app using ARCOre Geospatial using Unity's game engine. The app works perfectly on Apple devices - unsurprisingly! But with Android it has been a different story. I have purchased a couple of Android devices for development purposes: Motorola g8 power (Supports Depth API)  and a Samsung A51 (which does not support Depth API). My app on the Motorola device works and does not work on the Samsung.
There is very little information out there on ARCore Extensions Geospatial API - maybe because it is still fairly new. I cannot find any information about how the Geospatial API works and exactly what device capabilities it requires to "place" an AR gameObject in the ARCamera's field-of-view. Does anyone out there have a deeper understanding of the results I am experiencing with ARCore Extensions Geospatial API?
